# How to bind contained objects with live binding

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, livebindings

There is a blog about TAdapterBindSource and binding to objects by Malcolm Groves.
http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1084

This works fine but how can I bind a contained object from a class.

```
TContact = class
private
  FPhoneNumber: String;
public
  property PhoneNumber : String read FPhoneNumber write FPhoneNumber;  
end;

TPerson = class
private
  FAge: Integer;
  FLastname: string;
  FFirstname: string;
  FContacts:  TObjectList;
public
  constructor Create(const Firstname, Lastname : string; Age : Integer); virtual;
  property Firstname : string read FFirstname write FFirstname;
  property Lastname : string read FLastname write FLastname;
  property Age : Integer read FAge write FAge;
  property Contacts:  TObjectList<TContact> read FContacts write FContacts;
end;
```

On the form I have private TObjectList

```
MyPeople : TObjectList<TPerson>;
```

I also have two TPrototypeBindSource.
One for TPerson and one for TContact

```
procedure TForm1.AdapterBindSourcePersonCreateAdapter(Sender: TObject;
var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  MyPeople := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create;

  MyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Fred', 'Flintstone', 40));
  MyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Wilma', 'Flintstone', 41));
  MyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Barney', 'Rubble', 40));
  MyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Betty', 'Rubble', 39));

  ABindSourceAdapter := TListBindSourceAdapter<TPerson>.Create(self, MyPeople, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.AdapterBindSourceContactCreateAdapter(Sender: TObject;
var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  ABindSourceAdapter := TListBindSourceAdapter<TContact>.Create(self);
end;

procedure TForm1.lstPersonsItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  AContacts:  TObjectList <TContact>;
begin
  AContacts:=  TPerson(MyPeople.Items[1]).Contacts;

  //self.AdapterBindSourceContact.???  --> How to insert list
  //self.AdapterBindSourceContact.DataGenerator.SetList(AContacts, True);  --> doesn't work
end;
```

The problem is how can I load the data (Contacts) into the second TPrototypeBindSource.

One day later...
Once upon a time you get a vision.
I've change AdapterBindSourceContact (TPrototypeBindSource) into TAdapterBindSource

```
procedure TForm1.lstPersonsItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  AContacts:  TObjectList <TContact>;
  ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter;
begin
  AContacts:=  TPerson(MyPeople.Items[1]).Contacts;
  ABindSourceAdapter := TListBindSourceAdapter<TContract>.Create(self, AContacts);
  self.AdapterBindSourceContact.Adapter:= ABindSourceAdapter;
  self.AdapterBindSourceContact.Active:= True;
end;
```

But I don't know if this is the right way of working.

Comment: From a quick look into the XE5 sources I would say `AdapterBindSourceContact.SetList(AContacts, False)` should do the job.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: AdapterBindSourceContact is a TPrototypeBindSource and  don't have a procedure SetList, also TAdapterBindSource no setList

Comment: It's the BindSourceAdapter that has this method. A TPrototypeBindSource has a protected method GetInternalAdapter where you might get it. But I am not too familar with the LB architecture because I find it to be BS.

Comment: Yes, there is a SetList but I get an error Incompatible type TGeneratorRecord and TContract. BindSourceAdapter... you main TAdapterBindSource?

Comment: @StefanGlienke: what's BS?  (LB= LiveBinding)

Comment: excrement of a male cow :)

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I'm sorry to bother you but what do you use in place of LiveBinding? MVVM with Caliburn?

Comment: I am using DSharp bindings for simple things like binding properties to edit/checkbox and such and use a presenter approach (we mostly use Virtual TreeView where I wrote the DSharp TTreeViewPresenter) to display lists of data objects in a very easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will explore the DSharp.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the internalAdapter with your ListBindSourceAdapter will do the job.

```
with TListBindSourceAdapter<TContact>(AdapterBindSourceContact.internalAdapter) do
begin
   SetList(AContacts, False);
   Active := true;
end;
```